# Difficulties using Python request (POST) + API

Tags: python, json, api

Im trying to use a simple API with python. I get the data with the code below but, but I can't seem to parse it. When i print the type of variable "c" it says "unicode". I want a Json object or dictionary so I can use the information.

I have I tried various ways to solve this but I'm not sure if the output from the API (below) is actually Json or why it doesn't work properly.

```
import requests 
import json
import urllib

test1 ={
  "query": [
    {
      "code": "SNI2007",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "47.4+47.54"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "ContentsCode",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "HA0101A9",
          "HA0101B4"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "code": "Tid",
      "selection": {
        "filter": "item",
        "values": [
          "2010M01",
          "2010M02",
          "2010M03",
          "2010M04",
          "2010M05",
          "2010M06",
          "2010M07",
          "2010M08",
          "2010M09",
          "2010M10",
          "2010M11",
          "2010M12",
          "2011M01",
          "2011M02",
          "2011M03",
          "2011M04",
          "2011M05",
          "2011M06",
          "2011M07",
          "2011M08",
          "2011M09",
          "2011M10",
          "2011M11",
          "2011M12",
          "2012M01",
          "2012M02",
          "2012M03",
          "2012M04",
          "2012M05",
          "2012M06",
          "2012M07",
          "2012M08",
          "2012M09",
          "2012M10",
          "2012M11",
          "2012M12",
          "2013M01",
          "2013M02",
          "2013M03",
          "2013M04",
          "2013M05",
          "2013M06",
          "2013M07",
          "2013M08",
          "2013M09",
          "2013M10",
          "2013M11",
          "2013M12",
          "2014M01",
          "2014M02",
          "2014M03",
          "2014M04",
          "2014M05",
          "2014M06",
          "2014M07",
          "2014M08",
          "2014M09",
          "2014M10",
          "2014M11",
          "2014M12",
          "2015M01",
          "2015M02",
          "2015M03",
          "2015M04",
          "2015M05",
          "2015M06",
          "2015M07",
          "2015M08",
          "2015M09",
          "2015M10",
          "2015M11",
          "2015M12",
          "2016M01",
          "2016M02",
          "2016M03",
          "2016M04",
          "2016M05",
          "2016M06",
          "2016M07",
          "2016M08",
          "2016M09",
          "2016M10",
          "2016M11",
          "2016M12",
          "2017M01",
          "2017M02",
          "2017M03",
          "2017M04",
          "2017M05",
          "2017M06",
          "2017M07",
          "2017M08",
          "2017M09",
          "2017M10",
          "2017M11",
          "2017M12",
          "2018M01",
          "2018M02",
          "2018M03",
          "2018M04"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "response": {
    "format": "json"
  }
}

response = requests.post("http://api.scb.se/OV0104/v1/doris/sv/ssd/START/HA/HA0101/HA0101B/Detoms07", json = test1)

dat = response.content
b = json.dumps(dat)
c = json.loads(b)

print type(b)
```

This is what I get if I print the "response.content" variable.

```
{"columns":[{"code":"SNI2007","text":"näringsgren SNI 2007","type":"d"},{"code":"Tid","text":"månad","type":"t"},{"code":"HA0101A9","text":"Löpande priser","type":"c"},{"code":"HA0101B4","text":"Fasta priser","type":"c"}],"comments":[],"data":[{"key":["47.4+47.54","2010M01"],"values":["90.3","45.0"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2010M02"],"values":["80.9","40.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2010M03"],"values":["91.3","45.7"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2010M04"],"values":["83.9","43.5"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2010M05"],"values":["87.4","45.7"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2010M06"],"values":["97.6","52.6"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2010M07"],"values":["99.5","54.2"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2010M08"],"values":["105.2","57.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2010M09"],"values":["108.9","60.4"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2010M10"],"values":["107.9","60.7"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2010M11"],"values":["107.9","61.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2010M12"],"values":["181.9","106.1"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2011M01"],"values":["95.3","55.9"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2011M02"],"values":["80.1","47.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2011M03"],"values":["88.8","53.5"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2011M04"],"values":["79.4","48.5"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2011M05"],"values":["85.9","53.0"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2011M06"],"values":["90.2","57.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2011M07"],"values":["95.5","61.1"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2011M08"],"values":["97.1","62.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2011M09"],"values":["96.3","62.4"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2011M10"],"values":["97.0","63.6"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2011M11"],"values":["104.5","69.2"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2011M12"],"values":["171.4","113.9"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2012M01"],"values":["93.7","62.8"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2012M02"],"values":["78.3","53.1"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2012M03"],"values":["87.2","60.1"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2012M04"],"values":["82.7","57.4"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2012M05"],"values":["81.1","56.8"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2012M06"],"values":["92.8","66.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2012M07"],"values":["88.4","64.0"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2012M08"],"values":["92.7","68.0"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2012M09"],"values":["96.1","71.5"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2012M10"],"values":["92.4","69.7"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2012M11"],"values":["99.2","75.9"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2012M12"],"values":["147.5","115.5"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2013M01"],"values":["89.6","70.6"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2013M02"],"values":["75.5","59.9"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2013M03"],"values":["79.5","63.7"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2013M04"],"values":["76.2","62.0"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2013M05"],"values":["79.0","65.0"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2013M06"],"values":["84.6","70.5"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2013M07"],"values":["85.7","73.0"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2013M08"],"values":["91.6","77.8"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2013M09"],"values":["90.6","77.4"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2013M10"],"values":["93.0","79.8"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2013M11"],"values":["97.4","84.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2013M12"],"values":["151.0","133.0"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2014M01"],"values":["92.3","81.6"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2014M02"],"values":["75.7","67.6"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2014M03"],"values":["82.3","74.5"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2014M04"],"values":["79.6","72.7"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2014M05"],"values":["80.3","73.9"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2014M06"],"values":["92.7","85.9"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2014M07"],"values":["88.0","82.7"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2014M08"],"values":["94.4","88.6"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2014M09"],"values":["100.2","95.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2014M10"],"values":["103.0","98.9"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2014M11"],"values":["104.4","100.0"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2014M12"],"values":["159.9","154.1"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2015M01"],"values":["95.9","93.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2015M02"],"values":["80.5","78.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2015M03"],"values":["90.4","88.5"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2015M04"],"values":["82.6","81.2"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2015M05"],"values":["85.9","84.4"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2015M06"],"values":["97.5","96.8"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2015M07"],"values":["95.1","95.0"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2015M08"],"values":["93.7","93.8"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2015M09"],"values":["98.4","99.4"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2015M10"],"values":["105.5","107.5"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2015M11"],"values":["114.6","116.9"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2015M12"],"values":["159.9","164.9"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2016M01"],"values":["91.4","95.8"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2016M02"],"values":["84.7","90.1"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2016M03"],"values":["89.6","96.2"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2016M04"],"values":["87.9","94.8"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2016M05"],"values":["84.6","92.1"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2016M06"],"values":["95.0","105.6"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2016M07"],"values":["93.0","104.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2016M08"],"values":["96.1","106.9"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2016M09"],"values":["98.2","110.5"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2016M10"],"values":["103.2","116.4"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2016M11"],"values":["116.6","132.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2016M12"],"values":["155.6","177.2"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2017M01"],"values":["94.7","108.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2017M02"],"values":["79.2","91.4"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2017M03"],"values":["88.8","102.8"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2017M04"],"values":["80.3","93.9"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2017M05"],"values":["82.9","97.4"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2017M06"],"values":["94.2","111.0"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2017M07"],"values":["88.3","103.4"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2017M08"],"values":["91.0","105.8"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2017M09"],"values":["92.6","107.9"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2017M10"],"values":["97.9","115.2"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2017M11"],"values":["121.2","142.7"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2017M12"],"values":["149.7","177.7"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2018M01"],"values":["98.1","116.3"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2018M02"],"values":["79.0","94.6"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2018M03"],"values":["93.0","112.9"]},{"key":["47.4+47.54","2018M04"],"values":["85.6","104.3"]}]}
```

Comment: Try `dat = response.json()` which should give you a dictionary with no need for `dumps` and `loads`

Answer (score 0):

There's two strategies you can use, `response.json()` will give you back a `dict` with all the `JSON` in key-value format using `requests` internal `JSON` parser, the other if you want to use the actual `json` library is to do `json_data = json.loads(response.text)` and allow the `json` library to parse it instead.

In general the `requests` `JSON` parser is probably enough for what you need.

Comment: the response.json() gives me a big error message that ends with:                      File "C:\Users\bill.gates\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")

ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Try using the `JSON` library for parsing with the second strategy instead, if that doesn't work. The JSON is valid but it seems like that the `requests` parser is falling down on something.